# Parenthesis in regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

Using Perl and:

```
my $s="The Sea! The Sea!"
```

The pattern `/(.+)\s*\1/` matches `The Sea! The Sea!` because its matches the backreference `\1`

However, the pattern `/((.+)\s*\1)/` does not match `The Sea! The Sea!`

Why?

Comment: Because you have a broken backreference - `\1` is referenced inside its own definition.

Comment: Groups are numbered from the opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
((.+)\s*\2)
```

should work because inner captured group has become #2 now as outermost group is captured group #1.

Note that you can also use relative numbering of groups i.e.

```
((.+)\s*\g{-1})
```

Where `\g{-1}` will match most recent captured group.